# How to upgrade my manual central locking system of my Hyundai i20 magna to remote locking system?

Tags: hyundai, keyless-entry

My i20 comes with manual lock and central locking system as well.

I want to upgrade the system to remote key locking which would be a major assist in helping my car securely lock from distance.

Is it possible to upgrade just by changing the key to remote key, or any other extra accessories necessary to install for the new system. For a layman like me I thought no major accessories would be required to upgrade to remote lock.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you searched for this topic on here?

Answer (score 1):

If the same car was also offered with remote central locking as an option then you may be able to purchase and fit the required parts to retrofit the feature.

This would essentially give you the neatest solution that would make it for all intents and purposes as if the car had always had the option selected. This may not be possible however or getting the parts from Hyundai may be prohibitively expensive.

Another option would be to fit a third party kit to do the same job, something like the [Viper 211HV](https://www.viper.com/car/keylessentry/product/211hv/viper-1-way-keyless-entry-system) can be purchased for a relatively low cost and if you're feeling brave (or know someone who is handy with wiring) can even be fitted at home (**NB:** I believe the warranty on these is only valid if you have an authorized dealer fit them so a DIY fit is at your own risk!)

Answer (score 0):

i believe the hyundai is very similar to the Kia, depending on which model it is, but on the base models without elec windows and remote central locking you would have to fit and wire up a central locking receiver or universal central locking system, a central locking motor into the drivers door (the kia only has a switch which sends a signal to lock and unlock the rest of the doors) and would have a extra remote to attach to your keys to work the system.

Comment: Finally I located the wire on BCM which lock the doors by joining one end of test light to the said wire and the other to negative ground. However, failed to find the unlocking wire in the BCM. Any help to locate the wire to unlock doors is highly awaited. Thanks.